# distribution on the inverse Wishart matrix eigenvalues summation

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

Let $\lambda_1>\lambda_2>....>\lambda_N$ be the ordered eigenvalues of Wishart matrix my objective is to find if it is possible the distribution of:

\begin{align}
   s = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^N {\frac{1}{{1 + a{\lambda _i}}}} 
\end{align}
where a is positive and $N\ge 2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For small $N$ explicit expressions are cumbersome. For $N\gg 1$ the distribution $P(s)$ is a Gaussian. The mean is given by integration with the Marchenko-Pastur distribution, the variance is given by integration with a formula given in [arXiv:9310010](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9310010), Equation 17. Let me work this out:

The Wishart matrix is $X=WW^T$, with $W$ an $N\times M$ real matrix, $N\leq M$ and $y=N/M$. I rescale the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ of $X$ by $x_i=\lambda_i/M$, and define $\alpha=aM$. We seek the distribution of $s=\sum_{i}(1+\alpha x_i)^{-1}$. The support of the eigenvalue density $\rho(x)$ is the interval $(a_-,a_+)$, with $a_\pm=(1\pm\sqrt y)^2$. For $N\gg 1$ one has the [Marchenko-Pastur distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marchenko%E2%80%93Pastur_distribution)
$$\rho(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{N}{yx}(x-a_-)^{1/2}(a_+-x)^{1/2},$$
normalized to $\int\rho(x)dx=N$. The mean of the Gaussian is then equal to
$$\mathbb{E}[s]=\int_{a_-}^{a_+}\frac{\rho(x)}{1+\alpha x}\,dx=N\frac{\sqrt{\alpha^2 (y-1)^2+2 \alpha (y+1)+1}+\alpha (y-1)-1}{2 \alpha y}.$$

For the variance we apply Eq. 17 of the cited paper,
$${\rm var}\,s=\frac{1}{\pi^2}\int_{\alpha_-}^{a_+}d\lambda\int_{a_-}^{a_+}d\mu\frac{\sqrt{(\mu-a_-)(a_+-\mu)}}{\sqrt{(\lambda-a_-)(a_+-\lambda)}}\frac{1}{\lambda-\mu}\frac{1}{1+\alpha\lambda}\frac{d}{d\mu}\frac{1}{1+\alpha\mu},$$
the integrals being Cauchy principal values.
I have not succeeded in evaluating the integrals in closed form. Here is a numerical calculation of the variance for $\alpha=1$ as a function of $y$,

[image]

and a plot of the variance for $y=0.5$ as a function of $\alpha$,

[image]

<sub>For the numerical evaluation it is convenient to rewrite the integral in the form
$${\rm var}\,s=\frac{1}{\pi^2}\int_{a_-}^{a_+}d\lambda\int_{a_-}^{a_+}d\mu\ln|\lambda-\mu|\frac{d}{d\mu}\left(\frac{\sqrt{(\mu-a_-)(a_+-\mu)}}{\sqrt{(\lambda-a_-)(a_+-\lambda)}}\frac{1}{1+\alpha\lambda}\frac{d}{d\mu}\frac{1}{1+\alpha\mu}\right).$$</sub>

Comment: You wrote that the support of the eigenvalue density $\rho(x)$ is a specific (finite) interval, but the Marchenko-Pastur theorem gives us only limiting results, that is, the distribution converges to one with finite support. In practice, it could be that for any $M,N$, the support is infinite, right? Specifically, I am interested in proving that $\mathbb{E}\lambda_max$ is finite (for large enough $N,M$), and I can't seem to find such a result.

Comment: the probability density function of the largest eigenvalue is given by the [Tracy-Widom law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracy–Widom_distribution); it is sharply peaked around the large-$N$ limits $a_\pm$, with a standard deviation that scales as $N^{-1/6}$.

Comment: Sorry, I did not clarify enough, I meant $\lambda_{max}$ of the inverse-Wishart, not the Wishart. That is, I am interested at $\mathbb{E} \lambda_{max}(W_n^{-1}(m,I))$