# expectation of the exponential of the inverse of variable with Marchenko–Pastur distribution

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

This question is related to another answered before
[distribution on the inverse Wishart matrix eigenvalues summation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/360406/distribution-on-the-inverse-wishart-matrix-eigenvalues-summation/360408#)
my question is, is their finite expression for the expectation of
\begin{align}
{\rm E}[{e^{ - \frac{b}{{1 + ax}}}}]
\end{align} 
where $x$ is 
[Marchenko-Pastur distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marchenko%E2%80%93Pastur_distribution) variable.

Comment: just integrate $\int dx e^{-b/(1+ax)}\rho(x)dx$ with $\rho(x)$ the MP distribution; this integral  cannot be evaluated in closed form, but you can evaluate it numerically.

Comment: @Carlo Beenakker Sir is there closed for the Laplace transform of MP distribution

Comment: no there is not.